# Runtime exception when using a duration resource

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I'm implementing a custom control on **Windows Phone 8.1 (WinRT)**. All the animation elements in its **template** have the same animation **duration**. So I tried to move it the resource. Here is a code snippet:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="local:ExampleControl">
    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.Resources>
            <Duration x:Key="AnimationDuration">0:0:0.2</Duration>
        </Grid.Resources>

        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ExampleControlStateGroup">
                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.2">
                        <VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
                            <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseInOut" />
                        </VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
                    </VisualTransition>
                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                <VisualState x:Name="ExampleControlClosedState">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ShadowFragment"
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                         To="0"
                                         Duration="{StaticResource AnimationDuration}" />
                        // other animations here
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="ExampleControlOpenedState">
                    <Storyboard>
                        // some animations here 
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

        <Grid Grid.Row="0"
              // some content here
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

But, unfortunately, I encounter an unusual exception at runtime:

> Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is it ok? - you have defined *Duration* with a key `AnimationDuration` and you use `StaticResource SideBarAnimationDuration`. Probably it's copy-paste typo. Does the error dissapear when you remove the above code?

Comment: Sorry, it was actually a copy-paste typo during writing the question. So the problem still exists. I can't use duration as a resource.

Comment: Can you show where are you defining this *DoubleAnimation*?

Comment: I added a little bit more code to the example. Maybe it can help to detect the problem.